# Traversing html element from one view to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$('#addstflgnlink').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: "get",
        success: function (fk) {
            $('#stflgn').append(fk);
            alert(fk);
            //            alert($('#tmpcount').val());
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }

    });
});
```

here fk is partial view returned by ajax call. I want to grab #tmpcount in partial view fk. how can I do it in jquery.

Comment: please don't use `.live()` - it's deprecated for a reason. Use `.bind()`, `.delegate()` or `.on()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#addstflgnlink').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: "get",
        success: function (fk) {
            var tmpcount = $(fk).find('#tmpcount');//assuming tmpcount is the id of an element
            $('#stflgn').append(tmpcount);
            alert(fk);
            //            alert(tmpcount.val());
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated. Use `.bind()` or `.delegate()` or `.on()`

Comment: here tmpcount is id or class of a textbox inside fk(html) from ajax call. I have to find value of the textbox having id tmpcount inside fk.